# Custome \gls command to use shorthand

Tags: pdftex, glossaries

When I write, I usually use the full term and then after then use a shortened form to keep my writing concise, like so

> In the year 2075, The Federation of StackOverflow Planets overthrew the United States and created a single world state. The Federation, henceforth...

Right now, to do this in LaTeX, I do something like so

```
\newglossaryentry{federation-long}
{
name={Federation of StackoVerflow Planets}
text={federation of stackoverflow planets}
first={\textbf{Federation of StackoVerflow Planets}}
description={\dots}
}

\newglossaryentry{federation-short}
{
name={Federation}
text={federation}
first={\textbf{Federation}}
description={\dots}
}

In the year 2075, The \gls{federation-long} overthrew the United States and created a single world state. The \gls{federation-short}, henceforth...
```

I have my reasons for not just typing out "The Federation" (mainly if I later change "Federation" in "Federation of StackOverflow Planets" to, for example, "Alliance", then I will have to remember to go back and change "The Federation" to "The Alliance").

**Question**

Is there some clean way to assign a short term in Glossary, like so (note, this is an example **ONLY**)

```
\newglossaryentry{federation}
{
name={Federation of StackoVerflow Planets}
text={federation of stackoverflow planets}
first={\textbf{Federation of StackoVerflow Planets}}
short={Federation}
description={\dots}
}

In the year 2075, The \gls{federation} overthrew the United States and created a single world state. The \glssh{federation}, henceforth...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest method I can think of (using the extension package [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-only-short-only-desc}

\GlsXtrEnableInitialTagging{abbreviation}{\abbrtag}
\renewcommand{\glsxtrtagfont}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\renewcommand{\glsfirstlongonlyfont}[1]{%
 {% scope
   \bfseries
   \let\abbrtag\glsxtrtagfont
   #1%
 }%
}

\newabbreviation
 [description={\ldots}]
 {federation}{Federation}
 {\abbrtag{f}ederation of \abbrtag{s}tacko\abbrtag{v}erflow \abbrtag{p}lanets}

\begin{document}
In the year 2075, The \gls{federation} overthrew the United States and created 
a single world state. The \gls{federation}, henceforth...

Explicit use of long form: \glsxtrlong{federation}.
Compare with \glsreset{federation}\gls{federation}.

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]